# Trying to do a social media icon that when hovered on spins and changes colors

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a social media icon that both spins and changes colors when you hover over it. I can get it to spin but it will not change colors. Thanks in advance for any help. Here is my code and the JSFiddle:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3e45L1yw/)

**HTML**

```
<li><a target = "_blank" href = "link" class = "social-roll social-roll:hover"><img src = "images/facebook_blue.png" title = "Follow Us on Facebook" alt = "Facebook"></a></li>
```

**CSS**

```
.social-roll {
    background-image: url(images/facebook_blue.png);
    vertical-align: middle;
    -webkit-transition: all ease 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all ease 0.3s;
    -o-transition: all ease 0.3s;
    -ms-transition: all ease 0.3s;
    transition: all ease 0.3s;
}

.social-roll:hover {
    background-image: url(images/facebook_red.png);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(360deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(360deg);
    transform:rotate(360deg);
}
```

Comment: We can't see the images in the fiddle, but in any case a font/SVG would work better if you want to fade color

Answer (score 0):

Remove the img element and set the width and height of the `social-roll` to the size of the background image you're referencing.

You should also look into using sprites or svgs to avoid possible pop-in :)

## Update

Example: https://codepen.io/bradleytaunt/pen/RWedge

Comment: When I remove the img element the image disappears. I do not know what spries or svgs is. I have only taken html and css so far.

Comment: And you set the `social-roll` height and width to match that of the image you're referencing as the `background-url`? And the path to the image is correct?

Comment: Also, you can remove the class `social-roll:hover` from the HTML as it isn't needed.

Comment: Yes, I set the height and width of the image.

Comment: Sorry for not responding sooner. Below is a codepen of what you are doing, but instead of using an image, I'm using a color (since I don't have access to the images you're using)

https://codepen.io/bradleytaunt/pen/RWedge

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your help. I just can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to change the color of the image which is hard to do, i would suggest using an `icon-font` a good candidate is [Font-awesome](https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/).

Importing it simply with a link tag and using pre-set classes for icons like this `<i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>`

now we can change the color like any other font `.fa-facebook:hover {color:blue;}` and it will work.

[**here**](http://codepen.io/Ayeetu/pen/pjxKdY) is an example so you can see it in action